# Format of Date Variable Disappeared in Catx

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a SAS table for keeping descriptions and names of output tables which includes a formatted date inside. However the output includes date unformatted.

My code:

```
data tablenames;
infile datalines delimiter=',';
input description: $30. sastablename: $30.;
attrib datetoday format=yymmdd6.;
datetoday = date();
mergedtext=catx('_',sastablename,datetoday);
output;
datalines;
Table for Customers,TfC
Table for Sales,TfS
;
```

The code output gives **TfC_20688** for **mergedtext** variable.
My desired output for **mergedtext** variable is **TfC_160822**.

Answer (score 2):

You need to let CATX() know to use the formatted value.  Try using the VVALUE() function if your variables are already formatted. Otherwise use the PUT() function to apply the format you want.

```
data tablenames;
  infile datalines delimiter=',';
  input description: $30. sastablename: $30.;
  attrib datetoday format=yymmddn8.;
  datetoday = date();
  mergedtext1=catx('_',sastablename,vvalue(datetoday));
  mergedtext2=catx('_',sastablename,put(datetoday,yymmddn8.));
datalines;
Table for Customers,TfC
Table for Sales,TfS
;
```

P.S.  Don't use two digit years.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PUT() function to convert the SAS date in datetoday (the value of which is 20688) to the yymmdd format you want.

```
43   data tablenames;
44   infile datalines delimiter=',';
45   input description: $30. sastablename: $30.;
46   mergedtext=catx('_',sastablename,put(date(),yymmddn6.));
47   put mergedtext=;
48   output;
49   datalines;

mergedtext=TfC_160822
mergedtext=TfS_160822
NOTE: The data set WORK.TABLENAMES has 2 observations and 3 variables.
```